# Keras tuner and TF Dataset - batch size optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing a project to develop a CNN network on a large set of pictures for binary classification. I have developed my pipeline and I'm doing the hyperparameters tuning. I use Tensorflow Datasets as a feed to Keras. The Dataset is batched with the tf.data.Batch() method. This means that when feeding data to Keras, I don't need to specify the batch_size parameter. However, now that I'm doing hyperparameter tuning I would like the batch size to be one of the parameters. Do any of you know if it is possible? The data is fed in the keras-tuner.search() method, which is outside the model compiling where I can define the hp parameters.

One solution I was thinking of was to wrap the tuner inside a loop of different batch sizes, but this would be a) painfully slow and b) I won't be able to fully take advantage of the Bayesian optimizer (as it will not be able to see the batch size as a parameter and it would just change at random for the model).

Thank you!